# SNAT does not work to keep real client IP, MASQUERADE works

Tags: openvpn, nat, masquerade

I have 3 hosts: AAA, BBB, CCC.

1. Host **AAA** is an **OpenVPN serve**r with IP **172.17.10.1** and mask 255.255.255.0.
2. Host **BBB** has 2 tun interfaces:
   • an **OpenVPN server** with IP **172.16.10.1** and mask 255.255.255.0
   • an **OpenVPN client** with IP **172.17.10.50** (connected to OpenVPN server AAA)
3. Host **CCC** is an OpenVPN client with IP **172.16.10.50** (connected to OpenVPN server BBB). **It has routing to 172.17.10.0/24 via 172.16.10.1**.

[image]

**My goal is host CCC to successfully ping host AAA and host AAA to see the traffic from the original IP of host CCC (172.16.10.50).**

I have set up `iptables -A FORWARD... -J ACCEPT` on host BBB.

On host BBB I have set up **POSTROUTING** rule. For example, with MASQUERADE the ping is successful, but the problem is that this way host AAA sees src IP 172.17.10.50 (the ip from host BBB):
`iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.16.10.50 -d 172.17.10.1 -o tun17 -j MASQUERADE`

**I change MASQUERADE to SNAT, but the ping fails**:
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.10.50 -d 172.17.10.1 -o tun17 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.10.50`

The problem is that with tcpdump I see that the traffic does not exit host BBB and there is no traffic to host AAA:

```
root@BBB:# tcpdump -ni tun17
listening on tun17, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
12:16:45.777464 IP 172.16.10.50 > 172.17.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 30730, seq 1149, length 64
12:16:46.801548 IP 172.16.10.50 > 172.17.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 30730, seq 1150, length 64
```

**I tried to change SNAT to source IP 172.17.10.55** (an IP address from the 172.17.10.0/24 network), but again the ping fails and again the traffic does not exit host BBB:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.10.50 -d 172.17.10.1 -o tun17 -j SNAT --to-source 172.17.10.55

12:16:47.825419 IP 172.17.10.55 > 172.17.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 30730, seq 1151, length 64
12:16:48.849460 IP 172.17.10.55 > 172.17.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 30730, seq 1152, length 64
```

**Why does I can not use SNAT with --to-source 172.16.10.50 or even with --to-source 172.17.10.55** (which ip address is from the same 172.17.10.0/24 network) to ping 172.17.10.1 from host CCC?

The traffic seems to sit on host BBB and does not exit from its tun17. I see that the traffic goes from HOST CCC to HOST BBB, the traffic is forwarded from tun16 to tun17, but then it can not be send to host AAA with SNAT.

**The ping only works if the source IP address of the packet is 172.17.10.50. If I change the source IP to 172.17.10.55 for example, the ping fails.**

I think the problem is not firewall, nor routing, I suspect some OpenVPN restriction, but I am not sure. The two OpenVPN servers are in `--topology subnet` mode with /24 network masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **iroute** in ccd to manipulate internal openvpn routing table.

Otherwise openvpn doesn't know where to route back the packets. In openvpn log you must have a line like "MULTI: bad source address from client [IP ADDRESS], packet dropped"

Read more here:

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans

Comment: Thank you, adding iroute works! I even do not need masquerading anymore. I have been searching for solution in the linux kernel tcp stack and I did not know about the iroute internal openvpn routing table. Thanks, case closed.